# Network stopped working on my PC after an attempted Windows update was rolled back

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I have an ASUS PC Model X509JB, the WiFi was working fine until last week, during installation of an update it said that the update could not be installed and it rolled back the update (Security update for Microsoft Windows (KB5008212), but after a day or two I started encountering a problem with the WiFi.

Both the Bluetooth and the network driver shows a code 56 error and has a yellow triangle on them.

After some research I found out that this is associated with a VPN software, but I never installed any VPN app, I had a virtual machine a while ago and I deleted it before the problem started appearing.

The wireless adapter in network connection window has disappeared and is now empty.

What I tried:

- Network reset.
- Troubleshooting the network doesn't show any options.
- I tried deleting the updates that installed recently, one of them got deleted and the other update shows "an error has occurred. Not all updates were successfully uninstalled" while uninstalling.
- Resetting the Winsock.
- Deleting the network driver and reinstalling it.

Note that the Bluetooth is working fine even though it shows that error unlike the network.

Comment: Try an external USB Wireless Card. If that works, then likely your internal card has failed.

Comment: I'll try getting one in the next few days, but in the meantime i highly doubt it, because the pc is fairly new and the problem started occurring after the faulty update got installed.

Comment: Get the ASUS Driver Update App and update all drivers including BIOS (UEFI) and see if that works.

Comment: Tried updating all the drivers from the official website with no luck.

Comment: Can you edit your question to indicate which update(s) were installed exactly?

Comment: I think your Wireless card may need replacing

Comment: You could try using a Live CD/USB stick/whatever https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD to check if the network card works on another OS.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix the issue by doing a factory reset to the PC while keeping my personal files.